# Printing a record in Javascript

Tags: javascript, record

I have a record that contains the following.

```
var web = [{
            url : "www.facebook.com",  
            content : "Social Media Website." 
           },
           {
            url : "www.reddit.com",
            content : "A vast forum for different topics" 
           }] ;
```

I am trying to print out the url part of the record by doing the following

```
for(var i=0;i<web.length;i++)
{
    alert({"url":web[i].url,"description":web[i].content})    
}
```

but I am getting as an output `[object Object]`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can't alert an object, you should use console.log to show your object on browser console

Comment: What @Mr.George said, but also, spending some time to learn how to use the debugger in your browser's developer tools is time well spent.

Comment: {"url":web[i].url,"description":web[i].content} is an object and you alert this object. Alerts parameter must be a string.

Comment: If you have an array of objects that all have the same structure, try passing it to `console.table()` - blew my mind when I found out that existed.

Comment: you are passing an object to alert function change that with a string like so

    alert("url: " + web[i].url + "description:" + web[i].content)

Comment: So why someone should print and object on alert? Debug an application using alert isn't a nice way

Answer (score 0):

Alert takes a string, not an object. You can get a decent representation of your object as a string with `JSON.stringify`. Try

```
alert(JSON.stringify({"url":web[i].url,"description":web[i].content}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways:

use console.log to show on browser console your object.

print your object with alert like a string:

```
alert("{"+
"url: "web[i].url+","+
"description: "web[i].content+
"}");
```

on first case

```js
web={
  url:'your url',
  content:'blablabla'
};
console.log({"url":web.url,"description":web.content});
```